# What's the simplest way to convert an audio signal to a list of frequencies and volumes?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, spectrogram

I have a signal that is like:

```
input=[0,0.1,0.5,2,3,4,2,0,...]
```

And I need to convert it to a series of frequency lists and volume lists like this:

```
output=[...,[[50,100,325,950,4000,...],[0.1,0.9,4,2,0.3,...]],...]
```

I tried with signal.spectrogram(), but it seems to return a frequency average by time period, what is it not what I want. I need a explicit map of frequencies and levels by frequency over time.

Comment: A single sample has no frequency information. A window (being a time period usually with shaping at the ends) is mathematically required.

Comment: @jwal A sample can be resampled so its a number in the strict sense but also can be a time window, and so for sake of simplicity, I want to know what specific frequencies are sounding at a specific time, not for how long are they sounding, that data can be extracting by analyzing near samples.

Comment: How long is your sample? If it's effectively an [impulse](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fourier-transform-of-unit-impulse-function-constant-amplitude-and-complex-exponential-function), you cannot get frequency information.

Comment: @jwal it's an audio signal of the cumparsita (LOL), so there are many samples, each representing a time window that's equal to the inverse of the sample rate (that's more or less how digital audio works), I'm barely sure about what you mean as an impulse but I bet it is not an impulse, it's la cumparsita.

Comment: @jwal, this is like discusing the physics teacher that there is no instant velocity because there's no time difference at an instant, totally pointless.

Comment: This isn’t necessarily a programming question, but more a DSP question. You might want to try https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ that said, the answer is a Short Time Discrete Fourier Transform (STFT) a DFT (or commonly but incorrectly FFT) over successive overlapping windows of time domain signal

Comment: One problem above is the misunderstanding between “sample” a single data point / measurement of a continuous signal and “sample” a short recording of audio. In general, use the first definition when talking to the DSP community.

Comment: If you need to do this in Python, my first recommendation is to engage with the staff at your institute. If that proves to be a complete brickwall, I’d suggest flagging it up to your student rep or union. While you wait, you might benefit from exploring the search tag queries on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%2bfft?tab=Votes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it if it helps anyone in the future, although some libraries probably do it altogether:

```
spectrogram = []
N_window = ...
shift = ...
SAMPLING_RATE = ...
frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(N_window, d = 1/SAMPLING_RATE) # get frequencies list

spectrogram = []
for i in range((len(signal) - N_window)//shift): # run through all windows that fit in signal
    window = signal[i*shift : (i*shift) + N_window] # get window to compute DFT on
    amplitudes = np.abs(np.fft.fft(window)) # get amplitudes of complex values
    spectrogram.append([frequencies, amplitudes])
```

This will give you a spectrogram as a list of lists [frequencies, volumes]

Few remarks:

- The frequencies are all the same if you take the same windows, so you actually only need the list of amplitudes and one frequencies list
- The window size and shift are up to you, window size will set how much you are precise in frequency vs in time localization of your window, shift will change how much your spectrogram is smooth
- SAMPLING_RATE depends of your recording (how many samples/s)